# OpenGl Billboards with Fix Position

Tags: opengl, 3d

I am creating a tree in opengl and it is working fine..It is basically 2d tree so I am adding Billboards...
I am getting issue of offset when i move my camera the tree goes from its place to another along camera..
I am trying everything I know to fix this but not successfull...
Helping code from http://lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/billboardingtut.pdf

Can you help me out with this?

Here is the Billboard code

```
void billboardCheatCylindricalBegin() {

    float modelview[16];
    int i, j;

    // save the current modelview matrix
    glPushMatrix();

    // get the current modelview matrix
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i += 2)
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                modelview[i * 4 + j] = 1.0;
            else
                modelview[i * 4 + j] = 0.0;
        }

    // set the modelview matrix
    glLoadMatrixf(modelview);
}

Tree(); //my tree call which works fine without billboard in 2d but moves with camera while using Billboard

void billboardEnd() {

    // restore the previously 
    // stored modelview matrix
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the top left 3x3 of the model view matrix to the identity matrix. Iterate `i` and `j` from 0 to < 3 and calculate the index of the field by `i * 4 + j`.
You incorrectly increase `i` by 2 instead of `1`:

<s>`for (i = 0; i < 3; i += 2)`</s>

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
```

Complete algorithm

```cpp
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        modelview[i*4 + j] = i == j ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

glLoadMatrixf(modelview);
```

If the matrix has a scaling component, you need to calculate the scaling factors and set the diagonal by the scaling factors:

```cpp
float *m = modelview;
float scaleX = sqrt(m[0]*m[0] + m[1]*m[1] + m[2]*m[2]); 
float scaleY = sqrt(m[4]*m[4] + m[5]*m[5] + m[6]*m[6]);
float scaleZ = sqrt(m[8]*m[8] + m[9]*m[9] + m[10]*m[10]);

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        modelview[i*4 + j] = 0.0f;
}

modelview[0] = scaleX;
modelview[5] = scaleY;
modelview[10] = scaleZ;
```

Comment: @Struggler What do you mean by "still goes offset"? Do you have a scale matrix?

Comment: I mean that it does not effect anything (Still moves along camera)...Yes i am scaling it using glScalef because after using your code it is laying down on the surface and so thin..

Comment: @Struggler Ensure that the projection matrix is set to the current `GL_PROJECTION` matrix and all the other transformations are set to the current `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)). Furthermore you've to consider the scale - see the answer.

Comment: Great Scale works fine with your code...My problem is still there...Tree(billboard) is not rotating around fixed axis but rotating in big circle and it feels like it is moving & changing positions with camera..It works without glTranslatef but it is on center like (0,0,0)... i want to change its position...

Comment: @Struggler You invoke `billboardCheatCylindricalBegin` right before `glBegin` and `billboardEnd` right after `glEnd`, isn't it?

Comment: I am using billboardCheatCylindricalBegin while calling Tree(); not while making tree..

Comment: Fixed it with your code thankyou...Just a misplacement of glTranslatef at my end